# CSS Grid specific layout

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I’m looking for a way to represent the next layout using purely CSS Grid.

Layout image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDxv3.jpg

My code:

```
<div class=“grid-layout”>
  <div class=“item”>1</div>
  <div class=“item”>2</div>
  <div class=“item”>3</div>
  <div class=“item”>4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply like below:

```css
.grid-layout {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(4,1fr);
  gap:20px;
  height:500px;
}
.grid-layout > * {
  border:2px solid;
}
.grid-layout > :first-child {
  grid-area:span 3/span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-layout">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

If you want always square try this:

```css
.grid-layout {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(4,1fr);
  gap:20px;
}
.grid-layout > * {
  border:2px solid;
  display:flex;
}
.grid-layout > *:before {
  content:"";
  padding-top:100%;
}
.grid-layout > :first-child {
  grid-area:span 3/span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-layout">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each of the child div would need to have the respective class name that the following CSS has. Increase and decrease the gap to the needed size,(1st value is the gap between rows and the 2nd is the gap between cols)

```
.grid-layout {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
    gap: 5px 5px; 
    grid-template-areas: "item-1 item-1 item-2" "item-1 item-1 item-3" "item-1 item-1 item-4"; 
}
 
.item-1 { 
    grid-area: item-1; 
}
.item-2 { 
    grid-area: item-2; 
}
.item-3 { 
    grid-area: item-3; 
}
.item-4 { 
    grid-area: item-4; 
}
```

Comment: Is there any way we don’t need to hardcode the grid areas?